# SQL query to retrieve all events matching a set of tags and no others

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have a table with the following attributes (id, eventid, tagid) where an eventid may have many tags. Let's have for example

```
1, E1, T1
2, E1, T2
3, E2, T2
4, E2, T3
5, E3, T2
6, E3, T4
```

In that example

```
E1 has T1 and T2
E2 has T2 and T3
E3 has T2 and T4
```

Now, I want to perform a query to retrieve all events with certain tags, but only those tags and no others, for example, I need all events with tags T1 and T2 **and no others**

I have tried with

```
select * from table where tagid in (T1, T2)
```

but it retrieves all elements :-(, I was thinking in

```
select * from table where tagid in (T1, T2) and tag not in (T3, T4)
```

but it doesn't work either

The only event that has tag 1 and 2 and no others is E1, ¿how can I query that?

Comment: Did you mean `IN ('T1', 'T2')` ?

Comment: I doesn`t. It is returning also E2 and E3 because they have T2, although they haven't T1

Comment: Note that id is redundant. And your data set is not representative of the problem.

Comment: @Strawberry I would expecting some helpful comment instead of "id is redundant", oh man !! nothing better to do today?, thanks PM 77-1 you solved my problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select id, eventid, tagid 
from table1 
where tagid IN ('T1', 'T2') AND 
      NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM table1 t1 
                  WHERE table1.eventid = t1.eventid
                  AND tagid NOT IN ('T1', 'T2'));
```

[**DEMO**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/d26b99/3)